# Изменение пути иконок навигации слайдера в js при посадке на WP

Tags: slider-slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть слик слайдер и кастомные иконки, при посадке на WP пути иконки сбиваются. Как как правильно подключать иконки? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Прописал полный путь в js файле
/wp-content/ .. и так далее. Вроде бы работает